# Python querying dataframe to find row with min value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a Genetic Algorithm to decide which customers should be serviced from which depots and which depots could be closed.

I have written a significant amount of functionality and have become stuck calculating the fitness function. The GA represents each depot as a 0 (closed) or 1 (open) so if there where 7 depots, it  would be represented as 0000011 (first 5 depots closed, next 2 open).

I then loop through and calculate the distances from each open depot to the customers and put the results into the following data frame with the PostcodeFrom representing the warehouse. If we take TS24 3xx as an example we can see that if it is supplied from NE38 9xx it has a cost of 169.558740 order miles whilst if it is supplied from CV10 7xx it has a cost of 1531.390340 therefore it is clear that this customer should be serviced from NE38 9XX.

```
PostcodeTo PostcodeFrom      ToLat  ...   orderMiles   volumeMiles transportCost
0   TS24 3xx     NE38 9xx  54.711137  ...   169.558740   1695.587397   2034.704877
1   EN11 0DJ     NE38 9xx  51.758065  ...  4521.600265  45216.002652  27129.601591
2   TS24 3xx     CV10 7xx  54.711137  ...  1531.390340  15313.903396  18376.684075
3   EN11 0DJ     CV10 7xx  51.758065  ...  1625.645014  16256.450144   9753.870086
```

What I want to do is create a new data table (or change this one) so only the row with the min cost (order miles) for that customer (PostcodeTo) is included. So only row 0 in the example above would be shown for TS24 3xx and only row 3 should be shown for EN11 0DJ e.g.

```
PostcodeTo PostcodeFrom      ToLat  ...   orderMiles   volumeMiles transportCost
1   TS24 3xx     NE38 9xx  54.711137  ...   169.558740   1695.587397   2034.704877
2   EN11 0DJ     CV10 7xx  51.758065  ...  1625.645014  16256.450144   9753.870086
```

I think the way to do this is some type of query where we select the row with the lowest order miles for each to postcode and then copy to another dataframe, however I have not got a clue how to do this.. another complication is that the depots will change each run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.loc[df.groupby("PostcodeTo").idxmin().reset_index()["orderMiles"]]
```

Comment: @HuddersfieldLad, Thanks. you can upvote if you found my solution useful.

Comment: Hi - I would do but I don't have enough rep points - sorry